# How to make fs.appendFile method of Node.js flush to disk right away?

Tags: node.js

I am using appendFile method to append content to a file. The following is an over-simplified version of that code. It does suffice to explain the problem. 
My problem is that if the process is killed, the content of the file lags the last data written thru appendFile. In other words, all the data that is passed to fs.appendFile to get appended does not get written to disk. How to get around this limitation? I would prefer NOT to use **sync** versions of any of the fs methods

```
  fs = require('fs');
  myVal       = 1;

  setInterval (function() {
   ++myVal;
    fs.appendFile("/tmp/test.d", myVal +":",'utf8', function(err) {
       console.log(myVal);
    });
  }, 10000);
```

~

Comment: If you put `++myVal` before the `fs.appendFile`, then the console log and the file will display the same thing.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat, You are right about it. My simplification of the problem was bad and I am editing it. The point however is that I am unable to ensure keeping the data on disk in sync with the append. Is there someway to get fs.appendFile to always flush the write to disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this in the call itself, but you can certainly call `fs.fdatasync()` to flush the previous write to disk. To do so, you must change the `appendFile` call to use a previously opened file descriptor rather than a string filename, so you'll end up with three steps:

```
// Open the file
fs.open(filename, "a+",(err, fd) => {
    // Write our data
    fs.writeFile(fd, data, (err) => {
        // Force the file to be flushed
        fs.fdatasync(fd /*, optional callback here */);
    });
});
```

Make sure you close the file when you are done with it. Personally, I question the value of this approach when such an easy and obvious option as `appendFileSync` exists precisely for this purpose. It will make the program more difficult to understand, without actually adding any value.

But it will work.

Comment: This is certainly helpful and I will try. But the option of using appendFileSync is out because my code is in the server and this call will block the entire server during the append and these appends are frequent and on multiple files.

Comment: The point is, `fdatasync` will do the same thing. Forcing the server to flush the file's data means it must go do that one thing. It will block the process. This is just a wrapper around the (usually Linux) `fdatasync(2)` system call, and the docs for that explicitly say "The call blocks until the device reports that the transfer has completed."

Comment: @Chat Robinson.  Makes sense to me now. I think you have a typo in your answer... fs.appendFile should be fs.write? If you can correct that, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Could you add a reference, which states, that appendFileSync actually flushes the file out to the disk? Or did I misunderstand your statement?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 21, Node now supports a "flush" parameter.

Use it like so:

```js
await fs.promises.appendFile(path, data, { flush: true });
```

See the [usage docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesappendfilepath-data-options) for more information.